# Deciding on the size of RAM needed for my database runs on SQL server (windows 64 bit)

Tags: sql-server, database, memory-management, amazon-ec2, database-administration

What are the factors i needed to consider when deciding on how much of RAM needed when deploying my database on Amazon EC2. 
According to my knowledge number of queries and the size of result of the queries needed to be considered. but is that all? 
How much of memory needed for a database size with 1 GB? I am new to this database administrator section when deploying my product. I am planning to buy an EC2 instance with 17 GB but it's too costly, so i wonder does my app really needs 17 GB.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Load Testing capabilities. After that, remember that [Memory and Sizing configurations may vary substantially](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2663912) from one SQL Server version to the other one.

So, try to create an environment that resembles your production scenario and go from there. Try to simulate concurrent accesses to measure, and voilà.

There is a [useful tool](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/07/sql-server-load-generator-free-tool-from-codeplex/) (and Free) you can use for that. The link is to the article of the great Pinal Dave. There you can follow it up to the Codeplex hosted tool.

As a complement you can use MS Task Manager, or, if in need of more specific stuff, use the famous [Mark Russinovich's Sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) (also free!).

Hope it helps,